# Visual Studio 2017 design report that prints Original and Duplicate

Tags: model-view-controller, reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

I'm working on my first MVC project (with Polymer components) and all the printing is done through a Visual Studio 2017 Reporting Services project.

I need to create a report that prints shipment documents in Original, Duplicate and Triplicate format. For example, a shipment document which has 10 pages (a shipment document is a set of header, body and footer), must print the first set of 10 pages as "Original", the second set as "Duplicate" and the third one as "Triplicate". 
Could anyone give me some suggestion on how to achieve this?

My first thought is to design all the three "sections" in the same report, but that doesn't seem a "clean" solution. :)

Comment: easiest would be to have a main report with three sub reports.. pass all necessary parameters from the main report to the sub reports. design the sub reports to say what ever you want.. Original Duplicate Triplicate etc.. it should work a treat.. I've done this many times and it works well.

Comment: I agree with Harry. 1 subreport that can print your 10 pages and can accept a parameter that you can use to pass whatever text you want to it. Then a main report that called the subreport three times, each time with your different text.

Comment: Thanks, I will follow your suggestions.